# Flutter compile assets into executable (windows)

Tags: windows, flutter

I'am using flutter for desktop.

The release folder (`flutter build windows`) contains the executable, the dlls and a data folder with all my assets including icons. Is there a way to compile these assets into the executable to prevent them from being easily copied or stolen.

The assets section inside pubspec.yaml looks like this:

[image]

Comment: use `Inno Setup Compiler`, you can specify all the files you need to be in the executable.

Comment: this wouldn't help, because after installation on target machine, all asset will be accessible on disk.

Comment: Yes right, sorry I didn't understand your question at first and now I'm also interested to know if there is a way.

Comment: yes I found a workarount that suits my needs. I converted the images to base64 and saved them as strings. To use them you just have to convert them back: Image(
        width: 340,
        image: MemoryImage(const Base64Decoder().convert(myBase64Image)),
      )